# Keyboard overlaps popup in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, keyboard, popup, windows-phone

I am developing a Login screen in which the user needs to introduce their data and then submit them.

Considerations which I had: I have thought about using a Page, but eventually I rejected the idea because if I put Login page before the MainPage, then if I go back from MainPage, then it would go to Login page, which is not what I want. And if Login page were after MainPage, then if I execute for instance the app for first time, without being logged in, if I press back, then it would go to MainPage which I don't want as well.

The problem: I decided finally to use a Popup. At the moment looks perfect, but when I want to use a textbox, the Keyboard overlaps that textbox, and what I want is to move the Popup upwards just like a normal page. I don't know if is that possible, otherwise I am willing to hear some alternatives.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: well, if you use page you can remove Back Entry from Navigation Services. Do you want to display the login page only ones?

Comment: The ideal situation would be the following: I have the Login page at the begining, and then once logged in, it would navigate to the MainPage. And once in the MainPage, when the user presses back key, the app would close without navigating to the login page.

Comment: i see, let me show you my idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `WMAppManifest.xml` remove the property of `Navigation Page` and in you `App.xaml.cs` you have something like:

```
 private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadDefautPage();
        }

 void LoadDefautPage()
      {
         if (StartForFirstTime)//tombstone local variable
            {
                if (!IsLoggedIn)//flag save it in IsolatedStorageSettings
                {
                    RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/LoginPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                }
                else
                {
                    RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                }
                StartForFirstTime = false;
           }
      }
```

finally remove Back Entry in MainPage:

```
 protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {       
            while (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack) 
            {
                this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            }
        }
```

It's just an idea, let me know how it goes (: